# MSP430 Launchpad, Even LED light up in C

Tags: input, binary, output, msp430

I'm working on a little self project, I want to use a dial so that whenever the dial is on an EVEN number a set of LEDs will light up in according too it's binary number.
For example:

2 will display: 000010

10 will display: 0001010

with 1 being a lit LED

The dial goes from 0-40 so I only require the use of 6 LEDs. However, i'm having an issue with the coding of an MSP430 LAUNCHPAD

```
int main(void) {
WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;   // Stop watchdog timer

int numbers[5] = {0,0,0,0,0};
int Leds = 0;

    P1DIR &= 0x00;                // reseting the P1DIR register
    P1OUT &= 0x00;                // reseting the P1OUT register
    P1DIR = 0xFF;               //sets register to 1 on all P1 outputs//

    while(1337)
    {
```

The code is very incomplete right now. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to look at the last bit of the number to make sure it's even, and then outputting to the LEDs.

The way I look at it right now is to have an infinite loop that will just watch for a dial movement and then display on the LEDs and then hold those LEDs till the dial is turned again.

Lastly, the input number will be a string. so that will be converted to an int.

Comment: Excuse me, but isn't 10 `1010` in binary?

Comment: Also, you don't need bit whacking to find out if a number is even, in first place. `if (number % 2 == 0)` is readable and will be optimized to `if ((number & 1) == 0)` anyway.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/And_gate http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_(logic)